# Keep insertAfter Element, Within It's Own Parent Element

Tags: jquery

I am using this in the footer:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery( document ).ready(function() {
        jQuery(".entry-meta").prepend(jQuery( ".posted-on" ));
        jQuery(".entry-meta").insertAfter(".entry-content");
    });
</script>
```

It is supposed to re-arranged some elements with an article, such as: date published, author, tags, and comments count to be below the article content, instead of above it.

The problem is, on a page where their is more than one article(example: Blog Roll), it inserts/prepends the all data(author/tags, etc) to every single article, instead of within each article, multiplying the data.

For example, say there are two articles. The desired results is to move the publish date, author, tags, and comment count within the first article below the first articles content, and the same for the second article. The jQuery script is doing that, but it also adds the First Article data to the second article as well, and vice versa.

How do I make it so that it prepends/inserts only within it's own article?

Here is a fiddle of issue: https://jsfiddle.net/gb14ugja/

**Vanilla HTML:**

```
<article id="post-239" class="hentry">
  <span class="posted-on" style="color:blue">Date Published: 1/25/2017,</span>
  <div class="some-title">
    Blue Article
  </div>
  <div class="entry-meta" style="color:blue">
    <span>Article One Author,</span>
    <span>Article One Tags,</span>
    <span>Article One Comment Count.</span>
  </div>
  <p class="entry-content">This is the Blue Article, the red articles content should not be here!</p>
</article>

<hr/>

<article id="post-84" class="hentry">
  <span class="posted-on" style="color:red">Date Published: 1/28/2017,</span>
  <div class="some-title">
    Red Article
  </div>
  <div class="entry-meta" style="color:red">
    <span>Article Two Author,</span>
    <span>Article Two Tags,</span>
    <span>Article Two Comment Count.</span>
  </div>
  <p class="entry-content">This is the Red Article, the blue articles content should not be here!</p>
</article>
```

**Undesired HTML Results:**

```
<article id="post-239" class="hentry">
  <div class="some-title">
    Blue Article
  </div>
  <p class="entry-content">This is the Blue Article, the red articles content should not be here!</p>
  <div class="entry-meta" style="color:blue"><span class="posted-on" style="color:blue">Date Published: 1/25/2017,</span><span class="posted-on" style="color:red">Date Published: 1/28/2017,</span>
    <span>Article One Author,</span>
    <span>Article One Tags,</span>
    <span>Article One Comment Count.</span>
  </div>
  <div class="entry-meta" style="color:red"><span class="posted-on" style="color:blue">Date Published: 1/25/2017,</span><span class="posted-on" style="color:red">Date Published: 1/28/2017,</span>
    <span>Article Two Author,</span>
    <span>Article Two Tags,</span>
    <span>Article Two Comment Count.</span>
  </div>
</article>

<hr>

<article id="post-84" class="hentry">
  <div class="some-title">
    Red Article
  </div>
  <p class="entry-content">This is the Red Article, the blue articles content should not be here!</p>
  <div class="entry-meta" style="color:blue"><span class="posted-on" style="color:blue">Date Published: 1/25/2017,</span><span class="posted-on" style="color:red">Date Published: 1/28/2017,</span>
    <span>Article One Author,</span>
    <span>Article One Tags,</span>
    <span>Article One Comment Count.</span>
  </div>
  <div class="entry-meta" style="color:red"><span class="posted-on" style="color:blue">Date Published: 1/25/2017,</span><span class="posted-on" style="color:red">Date Published: 1/28/2017,</span>
    <span>Article Two Author,</span>
    <span>Article Two Tags,</span>
    <span>Article Two Comment Count.</span>
  </div>
</article>
```

**Desired HTML Results:**

```
<article id="post-239" class="hentry">
  <div class="some-title">
    Blue Article
  </div>
  <p class="entry-content">This is the Blue Article, the red articles content should not be here!</p>
  <span class="posted-on" style="color:blue">Date Published: 1/25/2017,</span>
  <div class="entry-meta" style="color:blue">
    <span>Article One Author,</span>
    <span>Article One Tags,</span>
    <span>Article One Comment Count.</span>
  </div>
</article>

<hr/>

<article id="post-84" class="hentry">
  <div class="some-title">
    Red Article
  </div>
  <p class="entry-content">This is the Red Article, the blue articles content should not be here!</p>
  <span class="posted-on" style="color:red">Date Published: 1/28/2017,</span>
  <div class="entry-meta" style="color:red">
    <span>Article Two Author,</span>
    <span>Article Two Tags,</span>
    <span>Article Two Comment Count.</span>
  </div>
</article>
```

EDIT: I have overhauled this question with more data, because some had trouble understanding the problem that I am having. The fiddle I included as been overhauled as well, and hoply it will be more obvious as what the problem is.

Also, each article is assigned an ID with a random number. I have tried to  move the data around for each article ID(`article[id^='post-*']`) as well, but without prevail.

Comment: have you tried to use .find or .closest method?

Comment: Provide the proper code context where you use this

Comment: I added a fiddle demonstrating the problem.

Comment: @shireefkhatab I tried: .parents("article")

Comment: @charlietfl I updated the post showing the whole code and that it was in the footer.

Comment: I just realized I goofed the code order in the fiddle, so I updated it.

Comment: How is it determined what content gets `.posted-on` or `.entry-content` class assigned to it? Date? Or is it manual?

Comment: @zer00ne I have no control over the assigned classes.

Comment: @Xarcell that's frustrating I imagine, well take a look at my answer and see if it is a viable solution. I only changed the jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of selecting *every* `.entry-meta`, you should first find each `.hentry` and then work with its descendants. Something like

```
jQuery(".hentry").each(function() {
    var entryMeta=jQuery(this).find(".entry-meta");
    var postedOn=jQuery(this).find(".posted-on");
    var entryContent=jQuery(this).find(".entry-content");
    //...do whatever you need with them
});
```

Comment: I still seem to get dates .posted-on elements in each article in both articles. Attempting to debug...

Comment: it is still duplicating, or adding elements from each article to both articles, instead of each article.

Comment: Please post the code you tried. If that's not the expected results, it's not clear what you want to achieve. Please, explain it better or maybe post an example of how the html should be _after_ the script execution.

Comment: I have overhauled the article with more information and a fiddle to try and make it more obvious as to what the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

With the mess that is in, I'm assuming that OP has no control over the site because it's a cookie-cutter(clutter?) blog/CMS template layout. So working with what was given and not altering anything but the jQuery, this is what I did:

> 1. Sort out content by referencing tags with either `style="color:red"` or `style="color:blue"`.✎
> 2. Next, we use `.addClass('blue')` and  `.addClass('red')` to the appropriate selectors.✎
> 3. Change the targeted elements `$('.meta-entry')` the actual parents `$('#post-239)` and `$('#post-84')`.
> 4. Removed the `.prepend()` method and added `.insertBefore()` method in it's place.
> 5. Chained the `insert*` methods together as well.

**SNIPPET**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  // Classify content by the color
  $('[style="red"]').addClass('red');
  $('[style="blue"]').addClass('blue');

  // Chain methods for readability and performance
  // Used .insertBefore insted of .prepend()
  $("#post-84").insertBefore(".posted-on.red").insertAfter(".entry-content.red");

  // As above
  $("#post-239").insertBefore(".posted-on.blue").insertAfter(".entry-content.blue");
});
```

```css
.entry-meta {
  display: inline;
}
.some-title {
  font-weight: bold;
  text-transform: uppercase,
}
hr {
  margin: 16px 0;
  border-style: dashed;
}
span {
  margin-right: 6px;
}
article:first-of-type .some-title {
  color: blue;
}
article:nth-of-type(2) .some-title {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<article id="post-239" class="hentry">
  <span class="posted-on" style="color:blue">Date Published: 1/25/2017,</span>
  <div class="some-title">
    Blue Article
  </div>
  <div class="entry-meta" style="color:blue">
    <span>Article One Author,</span>
    <span>Article One Tags,</span>
    <span>Article One Comment Count.</span>
  </div>
  <p class="entry-content">This is the Blue Article, the red articles content should not be here!</p>
</article>

<hr/>

<article id="post-84" class="hentry">
  <span class="posted-on" style="color:red">Date Published: 1/28/2017,</span>
  <div class="some-title">
    Red Article
  </div>
  <div class="entry-meta" style="color:red">
    <span>Article Two Author,</span>
    <span>Article Two Tags,</span>
    <span>Article Two Comment Count.</span>
  </div>
  <p class="entry-content">This is the Red Article, the blue articles content should not be here!</p>
</article>
```

**FIDDLE**

```html
<iframe width="100%" height="300" src="//jsfiddle.net/zer00ne/pcqm0u2t/embedded/js,html,css,result/dark/?fontColor=FF9900&accentColor=FFCC00&bodyColor=141414&menuColor=010101" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

> ✎ **Note:** The selectors (jQuery objects) that are referenced by their `style` attribute are different in the Snippet compared to the Fiddle.
>
> **Fiddle**

```
 $('["red"]') and $('["blue"]')
```

> **Snippet**

```
  $('[style="red"]') and $('[style="red"]')
```

These selectors target an element's attributes `<div` **style**`>` with the square brackets `[]`. If given in a different way, there are error logged and at times only half the text was not rendered. This has got to be a bug, so do not expect these attribute selectors to be 100% on the first try. This is usually what the selectors should look like:

> ```
>  $('[style="color:red"]') and $('[style="color:blue"]')
> ```

Read this article on [CSS/jQuery (`.querySelector()` and  `.querySelectorAll()` work like this as well) selectors](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)

Comment: I added red and blue color for demonstration purposes. The colored text does not actually exist in the working code.

Comment: @Xarcell I figured that out, but how would you know which one goes where exactly? There's nothing in your code other than colors to dictate where each item belongs.

Comment: @Xarcell I see maybe you have overlooked a very critical aspect of your process of presenting your problem correctly. As your post is after a couple of edits you have given us only one avenue of recourse, that being you wanted all blue in one area and all red in another. I'm well aware that was by design to illustrate your objective. Now think on what in the real code do you see on the dynamic content that could possibly be a "hook". Like for example, do any of the elements have a `data-*` attribute or a timestamp or date?